# MYSQL using count(1) in the where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm doing facial recognition. I have a database of people from group A and people from group B. I want to check every person in A with every person in B. I have a number of different algorithms I'm running to verify the faces. To do this I set up the following tables

```
comparison (
    id int,
    personA_id int,
    personB_id int,
)

facerecScore (
    id int,
    score int,
    comparison_id int,
    algo_id int,
 )
```

So lets say I had an eigenfaces program running as my first algorithm I'm testing. Eigenfaces would have an `algo_id` of 1.

What I want to do is make a query that selects `personA` and `personB` from comparison where there exist no existing records in the `facerecScore` table where `algo_id` is 1 and the comparison is that comparison.

In other words, if I have already run eigenfaces on these two people, I don't want to run it again. Thus I don't want to select a comparison that already has a record in the `facerecscore` table with an `algo_id` of 1

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following which will find all rows in `comparison` which do not have a record in `facerecScore` for a given `algo_id` given by the parameter `:current_algo`

```
SELECT *
FROM comparison
WHERE id not in (
    SELECT comparison_id
    FROM facerecScore
    WHERE algo_id = :current_algo
);
```

In the scenario that you want to find all comparison rows for all `algo_ids` that do not have a corresponding record in `facerecScore` then you could use something like the following.

```
SELECT *
FROM comparison, (SELECT algo_id FROM facerecScore GROUP BY algo_id) algo    
WHERE id not in (
    SELECT comparison_id
    FROM facerecScore
    WHERE algo_id = algo.algo_id
);
```

Simply this query first finds all combinations of `comparison` rows and `algo_id` then removes any which have a record in `facerecScore` from the result set.

Comment: Yep, I was just tinkering with NOT IN myself. I came back to check and see everyone else had the same idea. Thank you!

Comment: @NateL I've updated my answer with a more generalized approach which doesn't require a parameter.

Comment: @NateL "everyone else" is hard to guess after 8 minutes

Comment: +1 for the "find all" version,, still `not in` won't use any indexes if present, so if performance will be bad, consider my answer

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who hates correlated subqueries (e.g. for performance reasons, if the original query wasn't optimised), it's possible with a left join and excluding any rows that were actually joined:

**Update:** Inspired by @penfold's "find all" answer, this is a join+union alternative if the list of `algo_id`s is known (and short):

```
select '1' algo_id, c.*
  from comparison c
  left join facerecScore f
    on c.id = f.comparison_id
    and f.algo_id = 1
  where f.id is null
union all
select '2' algo_id, c.*
  from comparison c
  left join facerecScore f
    on c.id = f.comparison_id
    and f.algo_id = 2
  where f.id is null
...
```

Or a more general one (not sure which one will perform better):

```
select a.algo_id, c.id
  from comparison c
  cross join (select algo_id from facerecScore group by algo_id) a
  left join facerecScore f
    on c.id = f.comparison_id
    and f.algo_id = a.algo_id
  where f.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it will return first combination that hasn't been touched. Remove the last part `Limit 1,1` and you will get all the combinations that haven't been touched.

```
SELECT *
  FROM comparison
 WHERE id
not in (
       select comparison_id
       from facerecScore
       where algo_id = 1)
 Limit 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT personA_id, personB_id FROM comparison WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT comparison_id FROM facerecScore WHERE algo_id = 1);
```

This is probably pretty bad on efficiency with the subquery, but it should give you the right results.  Possibly someone else can find a more efficient solution.